# MDX query output in SSIS with 0 to nvarchar(max) column is giving weird characters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, mdx, sql-server-data-tools

I have a very strange problem.  I use a SSIS script to run an MDX query.  This MDX query then outputs the results to a table.  I then use these results to work backwards to ensure everything going into the cube matches the source systems.

On this one particular column, the final result is `0`.  However, the parts of the `0` are lots of positives and negatives which end up balancing at `0`.

When I run the MDX query in SSMS, it comes up as 0.  When it runs it in SSIS and then pipe the output to a table, it has come up as the following values:
`-2.98023223876953E-08`, `5.73927536606789E-08`, `3.91155481338501E-08`

The column of the table that is holding these values is `nvarchar(max)`.  I thought about changing it to be decimal or money instead of `nvarchar(max)` but I have other columns in the same query which are an aggregate summing to 0 that are not doing this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the datatype of the column in the cube(visual studio).
2. If the column is used in the hierarchy then give the appropriate type in properties. Currency type also can be added.